# angular when to use curly brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular sometimes i have seen curly brackets but some times not.i search a lot but i couldn't find correct question

with curly bracket

```
ng-src="{{imageSrc}}
```

without curly bracket

```
ng-hide="imageSrc"
```

what i'm asking is why we cannot write `ng-hide` as

```
ng-hide="{{imageSrc}} // doesn't work anyway
```

why there is 2 different syntax for `src` and `hide`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply depends on the way the directive you are using is "declared".

If the directive has the following declaration:

```
scope:{
    ngHide: '='
}
```

then, you don't have to use double mustaches because the directive expects an object

If the directive is declared like the following :

```
scope:{
    ngMin:'@'
}
```

then, it expects a value. If your value comes from a javascript variable, then you have to use curly braces to interpolate the string contained into your variable.

**EDIT :**

It has been a long time since I read angular source code.

I haven't found any source code to prove my point :

`ngController` which expects a string is declared like the following

```
var ngControllerDirective = [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500
  };
}];
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L3

`ngMaxLength`

```
var maxlengthDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;

      var maxlength = -1;
      attr.$observe('maxlength', function(value) {
        var intVal = toInt(value);
        maxlength = isNaN(intVal) ? -1 : intVal;
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
      ctrl.$validators.maxlength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return (maxlength < 0) || ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue) || (viewValue.length <= maxlength);
      };
    }
  };
};
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L186

Comment: → In the end the answer is: RTFM for what each directive expects.

Comment: thanks you but should i view angular source code to know what to use?

Comment: @whiletrue read the samples. Most of the time you won't need any double mustaches

Comment: @while Read the manual: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: @deceze Thanks for included the manual links instead of just the RTFM rant.  +1 for the links that help.

Answer (score 6):

Beacuse they mean two different things.
When you use this:

```
<span data-ng-bind="test">
```

This means that angular will go to the scope and get value from there with test as key. So value will be $scope.test. But attribte value will be "test"

When you use

```
ng-src="{{imageSrc}}
```

then value will be evaluated and placed to the attribute. So value willbe $scope.imageSrc and attribute value will be $scope.imageSrc.

But. Not all tags can wait for evaluation. They think that value {{}} is correct and will not be changed. This cause to bad request. To fix this problem ng-src was created.

Comment: but in `ng-hide='imgSrc'` value should be evaluated and replace ? i'm sorry i'm confused

Comment: No. Lets split the problem. Here is our span:

<span data-ng-hide="imgSrc" class="myClass">Test</span>

Pay atttention to the class attribute. When DOM will be rendered, browser will see class="myClass". As it is in propper format, all will be fine. 

Then, angular rise. It will see data-ng-hide="imgSrc", goes to the scope and get a value. Attribute data-ng-hide value will not be changed. But value inside the directive will be!

Then! Directive will modify attribute class with it's own logic, depending on recently got value.  Thats all.

Answer (score 4):

You can't write because both have different meaning see this link
,It's all about expression and template argument.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

```
ng-src=template
```

You can find it in argument

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

```
ng-hide=expression
```

You can also find it in argument